# Changing Instance Variable used in another Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-web-roles

I have a WebService using .NET for Windows Azure. There I have a singleton class which has a method doing something in a while(true) loop. This method uses a instance variable from the singleton. I start the infinity loop in a new thread.
When I change the value of the instance variable (using my webservice), the value is changed. But in the thread for the infinty loop the old value is used.
The code looks like this:

Singleton Class

```
public class Singleton
{
    static Singleton _instance;

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new Singleton()); }
    }

    private Singleton() {
        this.Intervall = -20;
    }

    public int Intervall { get; set; }

    public void run()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(privateRun);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void privateRun()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // do something with Intervall Value
            Trace.WriteLine(this.Intervall);

        }
    }
}
```

Start the run method in WebRole onstart();

```
public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // start the singleton method
        Singleton singleton= Singleton.Instance;
        singleton.run();

        return base.OnStart();
    }
```

And change the value from WebService

```
public string setIntervall(int Intervall)
    {
        Singleton.Instance.Intervall = Intervall;
        return "New Intervall: " + Singleton.Instance.Intervall;
    }
```

The WebService returns really the new Intervall. But in the while loop the old value is used. So how can I change the value in the created thread?

Comment: Are you sure both threads are running in the same application domain?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that, by default, the compiler/runtime do lots of optimizations involving caching values.  This becomes a problem in threaded environments because each thread has it's own cache, so they're not mutating the same varialbe even though they think they are.

There are a few solutions.

The first is to use `volatile`:

```
private volatile int _interval;
public int Interval
{
    get
    {
        return _interval;
    }
    set
    {
        _interval = value;
    }
}
```

`volatile` is a way of saying, "this can be accessed from multiple threads, ensure that the caches are synchronized when this is modified.

Another is to introduce a memory barrier when accessing the variable.  The `lock` statement does this implicitly, but since the whole point of this particular program seems to be lock free programming, that wouldn't be preferable; volatile suits your particular needs better.

Comment: I edit this to my code, by same "error" in my thread, the old value is used after changing this